# Best practice approach to emit an action at the start and end of a stream of observables in an epic?

Tags: rxjs, redux-observable

I'm using react-observable to orchestrate the AJAX calls in my application. I've wired in react-redux-loading-bar to show a loading bar when the AJAX calls start and hide it when they finish. It works but it doesn't feel very 'clean'.

Is there a better way to leverage RXJS or redux-observable to make this cleaner?

```
import Rx from "rxjs";
import {combineEpics} from "redux-observable";
import client from "../../integration/rest/client";

import {showLoading, hideLoading} from 'react-redux-loading-bar'

import * as types from "./actionTypes";
import * as actions from "./actions";

const fetchEpic = action$ =>
    action$.ofType(types.FETCH)
        .mergeMap(action =>
            Rx.Observable.of(showLoading()).merge(
                client({method: 'GET', path: '/api'})
                    .mergeMap(payload => Rx.Observable.of(actions.fetchSuccess(payload), hideLoading()))
                    .catch(error => Rx.Observable.of(actions.fetchFailure(error), hideLoading()))
            )
        );

export default combineEpics(fetchEpic);
```

UPDATE:

After looking into Martin's suggestion of using concat I've attached a simplified version which I'm happy with.

```
import Rx from "rxjs";
import {combineEpics} from "redux-observable";
import client from "../../integration/rest/client";

import {showLoading, hideLoading} from 'react-redux-loading-bar'

import * as types from "./actionTypes";
import * as actions from "./actions";

const fetchEpic = action$ =>
    action$.ofType(types.FETCH)
        .mergeMap(action =>
            Rx.Observable.merge(
                Rx.Observable.of(showLoading()),
                client({method: 'GET', path: '/api'})
                    .map(payload => actions.fetchSuccess(payload))
                    .catch(error => Rx.Observable.of(actions.fetchFailure(error)))
                    .concat(Rx.Observable.of(hideLoading()))
            )
        );

export default combineEpics(fetchEpic);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I've never used `redux-observable` but I think you have so many `merge` calls while you don't need them because you're not working with a value they pass to their callback. I'd personally prefer usign `concat` because then it's obvious you want to emit values from Obseravbles in order:

```
const fetchEpic = action$ =>
    action$.ofType(types.FETCH)
        .startWith(showLoading())
        .concat(client({method: 'GET', path: '/api'})
            .concatMap(payload => Rx.Observable.of(actions.fetchSuccess(payload)))
            .catch(error => Rx.Observable.of(actions.fetchFailure(error)))
        )
        .concat(Rx.Observable.of(hideLoading())
    );
```

I don't know what `actions.fetchSuccess(payload)` or `actions.fetchFailure(error)` so I assume they don't return Observables (dispite their `fetch*` prefix).

Also, do you really need `showLoading()` and `hideLoading()` return values to be reemitted and part of the chain?

Comment: Your example doesn't quite work with redux-observable but your suggestion  to look at concat was exactly what I needed to simplify it a bit.  I'll post the updated version and mark this as the answer; assuming no-one else trumps your suggestion by the end of the day.